# How to add custom input option to select?

Tags: javascript, html, angular-material

I'm working with `<mat-select>` and I need list of options where the last option would be a text input with placeholder `Add your custom option`. User can select one of the options or click the last option (which is input) and text own option , once he texted he clicked outside of select and value has been set what User has texted.

the problem is when the user add push `space` to add whitespace, dropdown closes.

```
<select>
  <option value="option 1"> option 1 </option>
  <option value="option 2"> option 2 </option>
  <option> <input type="text" placeholder="own option" /></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an `$event.stopPropagation` should be adequate. In the code block below I used it twice:

1. on the `(click)` event, so when the user clicks on the text input area, the select menu does not close
2. on the `(keydown)` event as the `mat-select` directive listens for the space key and closes the menu if it receives it.

```html
<mat-select>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
    {{ food.viewValue }}
  </mat-option>
  <mat-option>
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Add your custom option"
      (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
      (keydown)="$event.stopPropagation()"
    />
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: Thanks , it works. Dont you know how to update a select value ? When I make on keyup of input this.form.setValue(event.target.value) selected value not changes but formControl.value already updated